# Convert double to byte array in dotnet

Tags: .net, .net-core, binary, type-conversion

Using the primarily the BCL what is the most efficient method for converting from a `decimal` type to a `byte[]`?

I've found value `Decimal.GetBits` which it returns an `int[]` which could be combined with `BitConverter.GetBytes` but is there a better way?

```ml
let decimalValue = 12.0m
let bits = Decimal.GetBits(decimalValue)
let bytes = bits.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray()
```

Given the following sizes:

| type | size |
| --- | --- |
| decimal | 16 bytes |
| int | 4 bytes |

I could assume that `GetBits` will always return exactly 4 `ints`, unroll the calls to `BitConverter.GetBytes`, and set the values of a presized `byte` array.

Are there any other approaches? I'm surprised there's no built in `double -> byte[]` function.

Comment: Just curious. What is the use case?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan part of building a hash to compare objects